# subtraction of two columns from different rows

Tags: bash

How do I subtract the value of column 2 of one row with the value of column 3 of the previous row and print the result in a new row in bash.

I tried with awk like this, but I miss the part to change the line

```
 awk '{a=$3; b=$2; c=a-b;print $0,c;}' input.bed
```

The input is:

```
NC_048323.1 21 29
----------------------
NC_048323.1 62 65
----------------------
NC_048323.1 128 179
--------------------
NC_048323.1     204     238
--------------------------
NC_048323.1     296     392
--------------------------
NC_048323.1     427     448
---------------------------
NC_048323.1     477     507
---------------------------
```

My desired output then is:

```
NC_048323.1     21      29    21
---------------------------------
NC_048323.1     62      65    33
---------------------------------
NC_048323.1     128     179   63
---------------------------------
NC_048323.1     204     238   25
---------------------------------
NC_048323.1     296     392   58
---------------------------------
NC_048323.1     427     448   35
---------------------------------
NC_048323.1     477     507   29
---------------------------------
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question and indent the data block with 4 spaces or put a line containing only `\`\`\`` before and another one after each data block. This way the data will be listed the same way as you see it in the editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this litte awk helps, some explanation:

In the `BEGIN` section the field separator `FS` is set to space and the output field separator `OFS` is set to tab

If there is only one input line, print it

If there are three input lines, save the previous integer value of the 3rd and the integer values of the recent 2nd and 3rd columns, then print them out, delimited by the output filed separator, but: If there is an integer value in `int_3rd_prev` make the desired calculation otherwise print the value of the 2nd integer value

HTH

```
awk '
BEGIN { 
    FS=" "
    OFS="\t"
    }
NF == 1 {
    print $0
    }
NF == 3 {
    int_3rd_prev=int_3rd
    int_2nd=$2
    int_3rd=$3
    printf("%s%s%3d%s%3d%s%3d\n", $1, OFS, int_2nd, OFS, int_3rd, OFS, (int_3rd_prev == "" ? int_2nd : int_2nd - int_3rd_prev ))
    }' \
input.bed
```